# Set form submit header

Tags: html, http, http-headers

Is there any way to set the **HTTP header fields** of a HTML form submit request?

I need to make an authenticated request to a URL, so I need to set a header field. I can't use AJAX because of cross-domain restrictions.

Comment: @manu - I've edited in your comment to my (now deleted) answer. I suspect the answer to your question is "no", but maybe someone else knows better than me. When asking questions, it's very helpful to give as much context as you can, so that idiots like me don't go guessing wildly at what you're trying to do!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. You can't set HTTP headers outside of XHR/fetch and plugins.