# custom headers through html form submit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe

Is it possible to send custom headers through regular html form submit and javascript?Ajax(xmlhttprequest) is not an option, I can use iframes and javascript but not xmlhttprequest. Is it possible to do?

Comment: what header do you need to modify? if it's a custom header, do you have access to modify the server-side code?

Comment: Nope. 
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047711/custom-http-request-headers-in-html
Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362295/set-form-submit-header

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with *only* HTML.  You need something to act server-side to grab the proper header file.  If your host supports PHP, the solution is relatively easy.  If you want to use forms, you can submit their info to a PHP file and use that to generate the proper include.